# How to dynamically read ldflags for boost-python?

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, boost-python

Currently, I have written a `Makefile`, which reads `ldflags` using `pkg-config`.

```
pkg-config --libs python3
```

Now, I have found `python3-config --ldflags` and `python3-config --libs` which in my point of view are better.

The problem that remains for me is that, I'm also using boost_python and I have hard-coded the flag for boost_python in my `Makefile`.
i.e. `-lboost_python-py35`. The problem with this is that, if someone else  uses this `Makefile` with `python3.4`, They have to change this to `-lboost_python-py34`. So, can this be made dynamic, in a way the `python3-config` and `pkg-config` allows us to do similar things.